# Checking System requirements for the application in java

Tags: java, database, swing, oracle11g, software-design

I am building an application using java and oracle database. I want to confirm all the required software is installed and working properly on each time the user open the application and show the missing software/configuration error to the user and option to close the application.Is there any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't from a pure Java perspective, nor should you.  That is really a job for your installation process.  Every native platform you deploy to is going to have a different way of installing software and a different place to put it.  If you really want to do this because you are doing your instillation with Java (and love writing more complicated code) you will need to leverage something like JNI or JNA to ask the underlying operating system what is installed.  This is fairly simple on Windows and OS X, however, it's going to be next to impossible on most Linux's due to the differences in each package manager.